# C# client HttpWebRequest on a rails application and reuse a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-cookies

I have a rails 3 application running on windows and apache server.
As I have to use NTLM I use the sspi auth module of apache.
As the auth module don't work well with IE (each request results in 401 and another request) we setup the rails application that we only use the authentication on one url `/login` inside apache.

The rails application has a `before_filter :authenticate`.
If we don't have a valid login we redirect (http 302) to the login controller, authenticate and redirect back to the original url (`request.env['REQUEST_URI]`).

On a normal browser login it works perfect. The web browser login any url, gets redirected to authenticate and redirect back to the target url.

Now I have a client plugin writte as a C# project. There I have to make some web request calls to retrieve some json data.
If I make a simple GET request I manage the client to work:

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;

if (isWindowAuthentication)
  request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Which results in apache access.log like this:

```
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:26:15 +0200] "POST /ror/ioi/start HTTP/1.1" 302 123
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:26:16 +0200] "GET /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart HTTP/1.1" 401 401
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:26:16 +0200] "GET /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart HTTP/1.1" 401 401
192.168.14.9 - rausch [02/Jun/2012:11:26:16 +0200] "GET /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart HTTP/1.1" 302 94
```

---

But the redirect won't work if I have to post data (like upload a document which I want to do).
So my approach was to make a request, store the session information and send them with the POST.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
WebHeaderCollection headerCollection = new WebHeaderCollection();

if (Common.WindowAuthentication)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Common.PortalUrl + Common.IoiStart);
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
  request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
  {
    headerCollection.Add(response.Headers.AllKeys[i], response.Headers.Get(i));
  }
  response.Close();
}
LogWriter.LogError("second request");

string boundary = "----------------------------" +
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = true;
httpWebRequest2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
httpWebRequest2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
for (int i = 0; i < headerCollection.Count; i++)
{
  string key = headerCollection.GetKey(i);
  if (key == "Set-Cookie")
  {
    key = "Cookie";
  }
  else
  {
    continue;
  }
  string value = headerCollection.Get(i);
  httpWebRequest2.Headers.Add(key, value);
}

httpWebRequest2.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
httpWebRequest2.Accept = "*/*";
```

This ends in this (access.log):

```
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:51:22 +0200] "POST /ror/ioi/start HTTP/1.1" 302 123
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:51:22 +0200] "GET /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart HTTP/1.1" 401 401
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:51:22 +0200] "GET /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart HTTP/1.1" 401 401
192.168.14.9 - rausch [02/Jun/2012:11:51:22 +0200] "GET /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart HTTP/1.1" 302 94
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:51:22 +0200] "GET /ror/ioi/start HTTP/1.1" 200 27
192.168.14.9 - - [02/Jun/2012:11:51:22 +0200] "POST /ror/ioi/upload HTTP/1.1" 302 124
```

For the `/ioi/upload` request I disallow redirection.

Inspecting the rails settings (some code in application controller) I get this:

```
request: /ror/ioi/start
#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x4114458 @env={"SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"thin 1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy", "SERVER_NAME"=>"thorx64", "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x41eaeb0>, "rack.version"=>[1, 0], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>false, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"POST", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/ror/ioi/start", "PATH_INFO"=>"/ioi/start", "REQUEST_URI"=>"/ror/ioi/start", "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1", "HTTP_HOST"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS"=>"10", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"=>"192.168.14.9", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"Keep-Alive", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"/ror", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1", "async.callback"=>#<Method: Thin::Connection#post_process>, "async.close"=>#<EventMachine::DefaultDeferrable:0x41ea700>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>"a1ef5e037607d12742a40a0793de973a5e68605ccf087ad1baedaee6d811687b82a0671b94da2c4a9af2b481a5346585649e83d2f56f2838a4aca8eedbfc93b7", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.remote_ip"=>127.0.0.1, "rack.session"=>{}, "rack.session.options"=>{:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :id=>nil}, "rack.request.form_input"=>#<StringIO:0x41eaeb0>, "rack.request.form_hash"=>{}, "rack.request.form_vars"=>"", "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"ioi", :action=>"start"}, "action_controller.instance"=>#<IoiController:0x4114548 @action_has_layout=true, @view_context_class=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_response=#<ActionDispatch::Response:0x4114440 @writer=#<Proc:0x41143b0@D:/Informer/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:43 (lambda)>, @block=nil, @length=0, @header={}, @status=200, @body=[], @cookie=[], @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil, @request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x4114458 ...>>, @_request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x4114458 ...>, @_env={...}, @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x4113390 @details_key=nil, @details={:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :flv, :file, :image, :auto, :sourcefile, :sourceimage, :sourceauto, :legacy, :edit], :locale=>[:de, :de]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @frozen_formats=false, @view_paths=[d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/will_paginate/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/usesguid/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/acts_as_tree/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/acts_as_solr/app/views]>, @_action_name="start", @_response_body=nil, @_config={}, @_params={"controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"start"}>, "action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"=>{}, "rack.request.query_string"=>"", "rack.request.query_hash"=>{}, "action_dispatch.request.query_parameters"=>{}, "action_dispatch.request.parameters"=>{"controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"start"}, "action_dispatch.request.formats"=>[text/html], "rack.session.record"=>#<ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session id: nil, session_id: "c068a38edeb9bfa71aa5bf7885af35cd", client_ip: nil, username: nil, data: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, "action_dispatch.request.flash_hash"=>nil}, @request_method="POST", @filtered_parameters={"controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"start"}, @method="POST", @fullpath="/ror/ioi/start">
HTTP_VERSION => HTTP/1.1
HTTP_HOST => thorx64
HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS => 10
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 192.168.14.9
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST => thorx64
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER => thorx64
HTTP_CONNECTION => Keep-Alive
i am a user?: false
session: 

request: /ror/login?ror_referer=%2Fror%2Fioi%2Fstart
request: /ror/ioi/start
#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x41eda00 @env={"SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"thin 1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy", "SERVER_NAME"=>"thorx64", "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x3e6f4a8>, "rack.version"=>[1, 0], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>false, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/ror/ioi/start", "PATH_INFO"=>"/ioi/start", "REQUEST_URI"=>"/ror/ioi/start", "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1", "HTTP_HOST"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"_ror_session=bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948; user=rausch", "HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS"=>"10", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"=>"192.168.14.9", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"Keep-Alive", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"/ror", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1", "async.callback"=>#<Method: Thin::Connection#post_process>, "async.close"=>#<EventMachine::DefaultDeferrable:0x3e6e668>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>"a1ef5e037607d12742a40a0793de973a5e68605ccf087ad1baedaee6d811687b82a0671b94da2c4a9af2b481a5346585649e83d2f56f2838a4aca8eedbfc93b7", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.remote_ip"=>127.0.0.1, "rack.session"=>{"current_user_id"=>49}, "rack.session.options"=>{:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :id=>"bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948"}, "rack.request.cookie_string"=>"_ror_session=bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948; user=rausch", "rack.request.cookie_hash"=>{"_ror_session"=>"bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948", "user"=>"rausch"}, "rack.session.record"=>#<ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session id: 712, session_id: "bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948", client_ip: "192.168.14.9", username: "rausch", data: "BAh7BkkiFGN1cnJlbnRfdXNlcl9pZAY6BkVGaTY=\n", created_at: "2012-06-02 11:51:22", updated_at: "2012-06-02 11:51:22">, "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"ioi", :action=>"start"}, "action_controller.instance"=>#<IoiController:0x41edac0 @action_has_layout=true, @view_context_class=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_response=#<ActionDispatch::Response:0x41ed9e8 @writer=#<Proc:0x41ed8e0@D:/Informer/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:43 (lambda)>, @block=nil, @length=0, @header={}, @status=200, @body=[], @cookie=[], @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil, @request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x41eda00 ...>>, @_request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x41eda00 ...>, @_env={...}, @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x41ecc80 @details_key=nil, @details={:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :flv, :file, :image, :auto, :sourcefile, :sourceimage, :sourceauto, :legacy, :edit], :locale=>[:de, :de]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @frozen_formats=false, @view_paths=[d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/will_paginate/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/usesguid/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/acts_as_tree/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/acts_as_solr/app/views]>, @_action_name="start", @_response_body=nil, @_config={}, @_params={"controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"start"}>, "action_dispatch.request.content_type"=>nil, "action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"=>{}, "rack.request.query_string"=>"", "rack.request.query_hash"=>{}, "action_dispatch.request.query_parameters"=>{}, "action_dispatch.request.parameters"=>{"controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"start"}, "action_dispatch.request.formats"=>[text/html]}, @request_method="GET", @filtered_parameters={"controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"start"}, @method="GET", @fullpath="/ror/ioi/start">
HTTP_VERSION => HTTP/1.1
HTTP_HOST => thorx64
HTTP_COOKIE => _ror_session=bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948; user=rausch
HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS => 10
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 192.168.14.9
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST => thorx64
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER => thorx64
HTTP_CONNECTION => Keep-Alive
i am a user?: true
session: bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948

request: /ror/ioi/upload
#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x4235610 @env={"SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"thin 1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy", "SERVER_NAME"=>"thorx64", "rack.input"=>#<StringIO:0x3b754f0>, "rack.version"=>[1, 0], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>false, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"POST", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/ror/ioi/upload", "PATH_INFO"=>"/ioi/upload", "REQUEST_URI"=>"/ror/ioi/upload", "HTTP_VERSION"=>"HTTP/1.1", "HTTP_HOST"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_ACCEPT"=>"*/*", "HTTP_COOKIE"=>"_ror_session=bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948; user=rausch", "HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS"=>"10", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"=>"192.168.14.9", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"=>"thorx64", "HTTP_CONNECTION"=>"Keep-Alive", "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"100058", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------8cf0ecd4ab52a04", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2", "SERVER_PORT"=>"80", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "rack.url_scheme"=>"http", "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"/ror", "REMOTE_ADDR"=>"127.0.0.1", "async.callback"=>#<Method: Thin::Connection#post_process>, "async.close"=>#<EventMachine::DefaultDeferrable:0x3b749f8>, "action_dispatch.parameter_filter"=>[:password], "action_dispatch.secret_token"=>"a1ef5e037607d12742a40a0793de973a5e68605ccf087ad1baedaee6d811687b82a0671b94da2c4a9af2b481a5346585649e83d2f56f2838a4aca8eedbfc93b7", "action_dispatch.show_exceptions"=>true, "action_dispatch.remote_ip"=>127.0.0.1, "rack.session"=>{}, "rack.session.options"=>{:path=>"/", :domain=>nil, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :id=>nil}, "rack.request.cookie_string"=>"_ror_session=bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948; user=rausch", "rack.request.cookie_hash"=>{"_ror_session"=>"bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948", "user"=>"rausch"}, "rack.session.record"=>#<ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session id: 712, session_id: "bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948", client_ip: "192.168.14.9", username: "rausch", data: "BAh7BkkiFGN1cnJlbnRfdXNlcl9pZAY6BkVGaTY=\n", created_at: "2012-06-02 11:51:22", updated_at: "2012-06-02 11:51:22">, "action_dispatch.request.content_type"=>multipart/form-data, "rack.request.form_input"=>#<StringIO:0x3b754f0>, "rack.request.form_hash"=>{"document"=>{"id"=>"20", "guid"=>"{ed20ec73-94bc-413b-b3a9-07b44ab6e624}"}, "file"=>{"name"=>"Dokument1.docx", "source"=>{:filename=>"Dokument1_201262114815.docx", :type=>"application/octet-stream", :name=>"file[source]", :tempfile=>#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1bfrx5x>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[source]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.docx\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"}, "pdf"=>{:filename=>"Dokument1_201262114815.pdf", :type=>"application/octet-stream", :name=>"file[pdf]", :tempfile=>#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1uzoxvw>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[pdf]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.pdf\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n"}}}, "action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"=>{:controller=>"ioi", :action=>"upload"}, "action_controller.instance"=>#<IoiController:0x4235748 @action_has_layout=true, @view_context_class=nil, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_response=#<ActionDispatch::Response:0x42355f8 @writer=#<Proc:0x4235550@D:/Informer/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb:43 (lambda)>, @block=nil, @length=0, @header={}, @status=200, @body=[], @cookie=[], @sending_file=false, @blank=false, @cache_control={}, @etag=nil, @request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x4235610 ...>>, @_request=#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x4235610 ...>, @_env={...}, @lookup_context=#<ActionView::LookupContext:0x42343c8 @details_key=nil, @details={:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :flv, :file, :image, :auto, :sourcefile, :sourceimage, :sourceauto, :legacy, :edit], :locale=>[:de, :de]}, @skip_default_locale=false, @frozen_formats=false, @view_paths=[d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/will_paginate/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/usesguid/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/acts_as_tree/app/views, d:/Informer/company/latest/ror/vendor/plugins/acts_as_solr/app/views]>, @_action_name="upload", @_response_body=nil, @_config={}, @_params={"document"=>{"id"=>"20", "guid"=>"{ed20ec73-94bc-413b-b3a9-07b44ab6e624}"}, "file"=>{"name"=>"Dokument1.docx", "source"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41ced28 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.docx", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[source]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.docx\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1bfrx5x>>, "pdf"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41cec68 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.pdf", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[pdf]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.pdf\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1uzoxvw>>}, "controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"upload"}>, "action_dispatch.request.request_parameters"=>{"document"=>{"id"=>"20", "guid"=>"{ed20ec73-94bc-413b-b3a9-07b44ab6e624}"}, "file"=>{"name"=>"Dokument1.docx", "source"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41ced28 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.docx", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[source]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.docx\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1bfrx5x>>, "pdf"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41cec68 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.pdf", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[pdf]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.pdf\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1uzoxvw>>}}, "rack.request.query_string"=>"", "rack.request.query_hash"=>{}, "action_dispatch.request.query_parameters"=>{}, "action_dispatch.request.parameters"=>{"document"=>{"id"=>"20", "guid"=>"{ed20ec73-94bc-413b-b3a9-07b44ab6e624}"}, "file"=>{"name"=>"Dokument1.docx", "source"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41ced28 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.docx", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[source]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.docx\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1bfrx5x>>, "pdf"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41cec68 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.pdf", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[pdf]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.pdf\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1uzoxvw>>}, "controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"upload"}, "action_dispatch.request.accepts"=>[*/*], "action_dispatch.request.formats"=>[*/*], "action_dispatch.request.flash_hash"=>nil}, @request_method="POST", @filtered_parameters={"document"=>{"id"=>"20", "guid"=>"{ed20ec73-94bc-413b-b3a9-07b44ab6e624}"}, "file"=>{"name"=>"Dokument1.docx", "source"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41ced28 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.docx", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[source]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.docx\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1bfrx5x>>, "pdf"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x41cec68 @original_filename="Dokument1_201262114815.pdf", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file[pdf]\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\rausch\\AppData\\Roaming\\TQsoft\\InformerOfficeExtension\\Temp\\Dokument1_201262114815.pdf\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Windows/Temp/RackMultipart20120602-10036-1uzoxvw>>}, "controller"=>"ioi", "action"=>"upload"}, @method="POST", @fullpath="/ror/ioi/upload">
HTTP_VERSION => HTTP/1.1
HTTP_HOST => thorx64
HTTP_ACCEPT => */*
HTTP_COOKIE => _ror_session=bfd6cdcd0650812edeb58c9a915e3948; user=rausch
HTTP_MAX_FORWARDS => 10
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 192.168.14.9
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST => thorx64
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER => thorx64
HTTP_CONNECTION => Keep-Alive
i am a user?: false
session:
```

So my question to rails professionals:

So I don't understand why all header data for the ioi/upload request are valid but the rails application do not reuse the session (as you can see the last two line above user => false and session id is empty).

So is there something I have to send again (modify C# client) or is this a rails issue? I think last, but I don't know what to change at the rails part to make the reuse of the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!
It was a issue in rails.

This little thing caused the issue :)

```
application_controller.rb

Line 2:  protect_from_forgery
```

This is to protect the application. Creates a security token to use on every ajax request.

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="sGeq9l+HfYotFbfuZFHqtmrMGBygMGZc2SjnmEwp9eo="/>
```

So the solution in this case as I don't have this in the c# client:

1. Create a handshake to get the security token and post this as well (to much work for me :))
2. What I did: Add a skip filter in the target controller: `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`

Conclusion:
It works to store cookies and headers like I did and send them with the following requests to "simulate" the session.